# Formatting text scraped with headless chrome crawler

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, puppeteer

The code below scrapes text from multiple elements on the page, however the text needs formatting (adding spaces etc) so that I'm able to use it elsewhere.

I have some JavaScript (working in the browser console) that loops over the elements, adding their text to an array and then turning that into a string, which does what I want. Is that code that can be reused here? I'm not sure where/if I can add it?

```
const HCCrawler = require("headless-chrome-crawler");
const CSVExporter = require("headless-chrome-crawler/exporter/csv");

const FILE = "result.csv";

const exporter = new CSVExporter({
  file: FILE,
  fields: ["response.url", "response.status", "result.text"],
});

(async () => {
  const crawler = await HCCrawler.launch({
    maxDepth: 9999,
    exporter,
    allowedDomains: ["example.com"],
    // Function to be evaluated in browsers
    evaluatePage: () => ({
      text: $("h1, h2, p").text(),
    }),
    // Function to be called with evaluated results from browsers
    onSuccess: (result) => {
      console.log(result.result.h1);
    },
  });
  // Queue a request
  await crawler.queue("https://example.com");

  await crawler.onIdle(); // Resolved when no queue is left
  await crawler.close(); // Close the crawler
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah i think you could add a post-crawling step in the `evaluatePage` callback applying your code:

```
 function cleanCrawledText(text) {
   // clean text here and return it
 }

 ...
 evaluatePage: () => ({
   text: cleanCrawledText($("h1, h2, p").text()),
 }),
 ...
```